# GRE mikrotik правила firewall

Tags: mikrotik, cisco

*Имеем головной офис cisco и удаленный офис mikrotik.
Между ними настроен GRE тунель (Пока без IPSec с ним отдельная песня)*

Сеть в туннеле 10.1.0.0/24:

Mikrotik- 10.1.0.90

Cisco- 10.1.0.1

Сеть за cisco 192.168.0.0/24

Сеть за mikrotik 192.168.90.0/24

*Поблема в том что sip трафик заворачивается не в том направлении.
Хотя пинги с удаленного офиса приходят с верным src address.
Иными словами пакеты до сервера назначения идут с "белым" IP источника*

```
16:56:58.435548 IP 10.1.0.90 > voip-main.ruan.local: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 1, length 40
16:56:58.435598 IP voip-main.ruan.local > 10.1.0.90: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 1, length 40
16:56:59.455200 IP 10.1.0.90 > voip-main.ruan.local: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 2, length 40
16:56:59.455229 IP voip-main.ruan.local > 10.1.0.90: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 2, length 40
16:57:00.471614 IP 10.1.0.90 > voip-main.ruan.local: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 3, length 40
16:57:00.471667 IP voip-main.ruan.local > 10.1.0.90: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 3, length 40
```

*А вот подключение по sip протоколу:*

```
17:21:44.851772 IP 93.171.00.00.sip > voip-main.ruan.local.sip: SIP: REGISTER sip:192.168.0.3:5060 SIP/2.0
17:21:48.881832 IP 93.171.00.00.sip > voip-main.ruan.local.sip: SIP: REGISTER sip:192.168.0.3:5060 SIP/2.0
17:21:52.911773 IP 93.171.00.00.sip > voip-main.ruan.local.sip: SIP: REGISTER sip:192.168.0.3:5060 SIP/2.0
17:21:56.961973 IP 93.171.00.00.sip > voip-main.ruan.local.sip: SIP: REGISTER sip:192.168.0.3:5060 SIP/2.0
17:22:00.972916 IP 93.171.00.00.sip > voip-main.ruan.local.sip: SIP: REGISTER sip:192.168.0.3:5060 SIP/2.0
```

*Настройка Firewall*

```
add action=accept chain=forward disabled=yes dst-address=192.168.0.0/24 src-address=192.168.90.0/24
add action=accept chain=output disabled=yes protocol=gre
add action=accept chain=input disabled=yes protocol=gre
add action=accept chain=output protocol=gre
add action=accept chain=input protocol=ospf
add action=accept chain=output protocol=ospf
add action=accept chain=input protocol=gre
add action=accept chain=forward dst-port=5060 in-interface=local_bridge out-interface=TO_HQGW protocol=udp
/ip firewall nat
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat dst-address=192.168.0.0/24 out-interface=TO_HQGW protocol=udp src-port=5060
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat src-address=192.168.90.0/24
add action=accept chain=srcnat dst-address=192.168.0.0/24 src-address=192.168.90.0/24
```

Настройки GRE

```
add allow-fast-path=no ipsec-secret=<ключ> local-address=<ip mikrotik> mtu=1476 name=TO_HQGW remote-address=<ip cisco>
```

Настройки cisco:

```
interface Tunnel1
 ip address 10.1.0.1 255.255.255.0
 ip mtu 1280
 tunnel source GigabitEthernet0/0
 tunnel destination 93.171.00.00
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Я правильно вас понял, sip устройства(за микротиком) должны регистрироваться на sip сервере(за циской)? Tracert по ip норм ходит? Резолвится в нужный IP? При отключенном файрволе норм работает? Маршруты статические/динамические? Корректно прописаны?

Comment: При отключенном фаерволе падает туннель, так как правила разрешающие gre отключаются. Маршруты динамические, но пробовал и статику, безрезультатно. Что именно нужно зарезолвить? Да поняли правильно, sip сервер за циской.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решён отключением ALG. А имеено отключением сервиса sip, именно он был виноват в подмене src ip на выходе.

Answer (score 0):

```
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat src-address=192.168.90.0/24
add action=accept chain=srcnat dst-address=192.168.0.0/24 src-address=192.168.90.0/24
```

Эти 2 правила поменяйте местами

```
add action=accept chain=srcnat dst-address=192.168.0.0/24 src-address=192.168.90.0/24
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat src-address=192.168.90.0/24
```